# Render single image perfect but rendered animation has objects dissappearing

Tags: rendering, animation, physics, constraints, rigid-body-simulation

I have finished a 650 frame animation. When I render a single image as PNG image the render is perfect. However when I render the whole animation as PNG eequence, the images making up the section where I am employing a Child Of constraint has the problems of the object under the influence of Child Of constraint disappearing from the screen. However the following section of the sequence when the Child Of constraint has no more influence the images render perfect with object back in sceneenter image description here.

First image is image 90 from the rendered sequence.
Second image is image 90 rendered as a single image.

What could be causing this problem and how to  fix it?

[image: Object Missing]

[image: Object Present]

Comment: It's like spot the difference, I take it it the snowman's hat is the object.  Might help if you upload blend to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have just sorted the problem. I reworked the file before I had the problem and now its working, although I never found what the actual cause was.